# Dart Flutter using Curl getting "Unexpected Extension Byte" error when using >> to append to file on MacOS

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, curl

I think I'm misunderstanding something, formatting of the command maybe,  but when I change this from using --output to using >> so that it appends to rather than just overwrites, like this:

```
var result = await Process.run('curl', ['--verbose', '--range', '$curStart-$curEnd','$baseURL$filename','--output', '$tempPath/$storedName']);
```

to this

```
var result = await Process.run('curl', ['--verbose', '--range', '$curStart-$curEnd','$baseURL$filename','>>', '$tempPath/$storedName']);
```

I get this error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 1336)
#0      _Utf8Decoder.convertChunked (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1891:7)
#1      _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:314:28)
#2      _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:310:5)
#3      _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18)
#4      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)
#5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
#6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
#7      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
#8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#10     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:733:19)
#11     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:607:7)
#12     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:554:5)
#13     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2160:41)
#14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370:13)
#15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
#16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
#17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#18     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#19     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:733:19)
#20     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:607:7)
#21     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:554:5)
#22     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1696:33)
#23     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1208:14)
#24     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#25     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

But if I do the same call directly on the terminal like this

```
curl https://file I'm requesting >> `path/file I'm storing`
```

Comment: Comment about the `shell` tag: Your original code doesn't involve any shell at all; `Process.run()` directly starts your target program, with no shell anywhere in the way. That said, as someone who was pulled in here via the shell tag, I can offer a fix that involves a shell, even if I don't have particularly much understanding of dart. Whereas if you want only dart-native fixes... it might be better to leave the shell tag out.

Comment: removed shell tag. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>>` is a shell redirection. It isn't recognized or honored by `curl` -- it's only recognized by a shell, as an instruction about steps to follow before starting `curl`.

Hopefully, Dart will have a sufficiently powerful standard library to do that redirection natively -- for example, in Python, you pass `stdout = open(f'{tempPath}/{storedName}', 'a')` as an argument to `subprocess.Popen` to perform that redirection.

However, if dart doesn't give you a way to do that, the fallback is to start a shell:

```dart
var result = await Process.run('sh', [
  '-c', 'exec "\$@" >>"\$0"', '$tempPath/$storedName',
  'curl',
  '--verbose',
  '--range', '$curStart-$curEnd',
  '$baseURL$filename'
]);
```

`dart` is not a language I'm well familiar with, so if the literal syntax needs to be fixed up, please do that -- the *exact string* passed to the shell as the argument after the `-c` should be `exec "$@" >>"$0"`. (`"$0"` refers to the position-0 argument, conventionally the name of the program being run but we're abusing it to store the name of the output file; `"$@"` refers to all arguments from `$1` and onward). Note that `>>` can't be passed as part of a parameter value; the shell *must* parse it as code, rather than receiving it as data, for it to work as a redirection operator.

Here, we tell `dart` to start a shell directed to run all its arguments (implicitly, except `$0`) with output redirected *to* `$0`. That shell then starts curl -- and because of the `exec`, it runs curl in its existing PID rather than starting a subprocess, so the parent process can directly monitor and signal the copy of curl, instead of the shell that launched it.

Comment: wow.. that's working fine.  Thanks so much.  
PS. for others looking, why am I not using http instead of curl?  I'm finding Curl to be slightly faster than the dart http package. That's the only reason.

Comment: Interesting. It might be worth keeping an eye on whether that stays the case -- there's a significant penalty involved in starting up an external process, so it shouldn't be hard for dart's built-implementation to be faster in a future version if this is something they work on.